# Google Chrome Extension with OAuth

Tags: oauth, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to integrate OAuth with my chrome extension. I am following the tutorial by google: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html

I create ExOauth from the background.js (defined by me and it is loaded by background.html).

```
var oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({
    'request_url': 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
    'authorize_url': 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
    'access_url': 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken',
    'consumer_key': 'anonymous',
    'consumer_secret': 'anonymous',
    'scope': 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/',
    'app_name': Test app'
  });

 oauth.authorize(onAuthorized);
```

Here is the OnAuthorized method:

```
onAuthorized = function () {
    // Start my application logic.
};
```

Am I missing something here? When I load the extension, it opens up several "Redirecting...." tabs. [image: Multiple Oauth tabs]

Comment: I am still have this problem and it keeps opening new tabs. how did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial seems to be missing one file. If you open `chrome_ex_oauth.html`, you'll see that it tries to load 3 js files:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="chrome_ex_oauthsimple.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chrome_ex_oauth.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="onload.js"></script>
```

The `onload.js` file is not provided. The [OAuth contacts example](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/extensions/oauth_contacts/onload.js?revision=143454) provides such a file, with the following content:

```js
window.onload = function() {
     ChromeExOAuth.initCallbackPage();
}
```

After adding this file, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: I did this file and still it keeps on opening hundreds of tabs. How do I solve this?

Comment: @avi I have run into this issue with the Chrome OAuth ext opening hundreds of tabs.  Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

I know the Question is a bit older but i had the same Problem.

I made the mistake that i want to authenticate two oauth endpoint and call both times the ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({})
Obviously that's wrong cause i dont want to init my background page twice.

Maybe using the ..._oauthsimple.js will fix that